# Exit if statement when try catch in different function has hit

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch

I have the following method where I send files to an sFTP server:

```
public static int Send(string fileName)
    {
        var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(_host, _userName, new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(_userName, _password));

        // upload file
        using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ". No internet connection");
            }
            
            try
            {
                client.ChangeDirectory($"/{Environment.MachineName}/{_date.ToString("d")}");
            }
            catch(Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + ". No internet connection");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                client.CreateDirectory($"/{Environment.MachineName}/{_date.ToString("d")}");
                client.ChangeDirectory($"/{Environment.MachineName}/{_date.ToString("d")}");
            }

            using (var uploadFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.UploadFile(uploadFileStream, fileName, true);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No internet connection");
                }
                
            }

            client.Disconnect();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

And then I've made another method, where I check if the files have actually been uploaded and if it hasn't, then it uploads them.
However, I want to add to the method, so that it deletes the folder and files locally on the machine, if it has been uploaded:

```
foreach (string filePath in sendLocalFiles)
{
     var path = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
     if (!client.Exists(filePath))
     {
          Send(filePath);
          File.Delete(filePath);
          Directory.Delete($@"C:\Temp\{Environment.MachineName}\{_date.ToString("d")}\{path}", true);
     }
}
```

The problem is, because I have a try/catch in my `public static int Send(string fileName)` method, I can't get it to exit the if statement, if the Send(filePath); fails.

How can I exit the if statement, if the Send() method fails?
Note: I did try and use a try/catch - that didn't work

Comment: Could you not just check the result of `Send()` and then use `break;` to breakout if it fails?

Comment: Although it is not a best practice, you can `return` -1 for your failed operations and then check and 'break' the if statement.

Comment: Best exception handling is to _not_ write any `try..catch` statements at all.

Comment: Looks like you are handling the "everything is fine" situation using the return value '0'. But when errors happened, you never returned a different return value. Also, your calling code should store the returned value in a variable and adapt the logic if it failed to whatever you want it to do `if (Send(filePath) != 0) throw new Exception("Boom!");`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I did a mix between @Cleptus and Mohi :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just use `break;` to breakout of the IF if the result fails?

Change `Send()` to return a `bool` and in the exceptions return `false`. Then do something like

```
if(!Send(filePath))
    break;
etc
```

Should break out of the IF